# Need a way to extract string constants from source code

Tags: javascript, regex, parsing, utility

I need to do the following:

- extract the strings, obviously
- ignore comments in source code, `//` and multi-line `/* ... */`
- handle quotes within strings: `'But he wasn\'t here!'`, `"It just won't \"do it\"!"`

I was trying to come up with something using `grep`, but I'm having trouble with quotes within quotes and multi-line comments. I think this is beyond what `grep` can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at `xgettext` also `xgettest-js` - it should do what you're looking for!